My Game Engine OnUpdate Method Is Not Working Correctly
I'm working on a simple game engine in C#, and my OnUpdate method is not behaving as expected. It should update every frame, but instead, it takes around 6 seconds to update something that should only take about 0.4 milliseconds. I'm not sure what is causing this delay.

What I think is causing the problem:
The issue seems to occur in the GameLoop method, where the OnUpdate method isn't running as quickly as expected. Even though I included Thread.Sleep(1) to prevent high CPU usage, the updates are significantly slower than they should be. In my DemoGame class, the OnUpdate method increments a timer and destroys a player object after a certain time, but this process takes much longer than it should.

What i tried and what i was expecting:
I tried simplifying the OnUpdate method to only increment a counter and check a condition to destroy a player object. I expected this would take only a few milliseconds to execute, allowing the game to update smoothly every frame. However, I'm seeing a much longer update time, which is affecting the overall performance of my game engine.

Code:
GameEngine.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace GameEngine.GameEngine
{
    class Canvas : Form
    {
        public Canvas()
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        }
    }

    public abstract class GameEngine
    {
        private Vector2 screenSize = new Vector2(512, 512);
        private string title = "New Game";
        private Canvas window = null;
        private Thread gameLoopThread = null;

        private static List<Shape2D> allShapes = new List<Shape2D>();

        public Color backgroundColor;

        public GameEngine(Vector2 screenSize, string title)
        {
            Log.Info("Game is starting...");
            this.screenSize = screenSize;
            this.title = title;

            window = new Canvas();
            window.Size = new Size((int)this.screenSize.x, (int)this.screenSize.y);
            window.Text = this.title;
            window.Paint += Renderer;

            gameLoopThread = new Thread(GameLoop);
            gameLoopThread.Start();

            Application.Run(window);
        }

        public static void RegisterShape(Shape2D shape)
        {
            allShapes.Add(shape);
        }

        public static void UnRegisterShape(Shape2D shape)
        {
            allShapes.Remove(shape);
        }

        void GameLoop()
        {
            OnLoad();
            while (gameLoopThread.IsAlive)
            {
                try
                {
                    OnDraw();
                    window.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { window.Refresh(); });
                    OnUpdate();
                    Thread.Sleep(1); // Sleep for 1ms to prevent high CPU usage
                }
                catch
                {
                    Log.Eror("Game is not found...");
                }
            }
        }

        private void Renderer(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.Clear(backgroundColor);

            foreach (Shape2D shape in allShapes)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), shape.postion.x, shape.postion.y, shape.scale.x, shape.scale.y);
            }
        }

        public abstract void OnLoad();
        public abstract void OnUpdate();
        public abstract void OnDraw();
    }
}


DemoGame.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GameEngine.GameEngine;

namespace GameEngine.GameEngine
{
    class DemoGame : GameEngine
    {
        Shape2D player;
        public DemoGame() : base(new Vector2(615, 615), "Game") {}

        public override void OnDraw()
        {
        }

        public override void OnLoad()
        {
            backgroundColor = Color.Black;
            player = new Shape2D(new Vector2(10, 10), new Vector2(10, 10), "test");
        }

        int time = 0;
        public override void OnUpdate()
        {
            if (time > 400)
            {
                player.DestroySelf();
            }
            time++;
        }
    }
}

Question:
What could be causing the slow performance in my OnUpdate method? How can I fix it to ensure it runs every frame without such a large delay?

A "frame" is of fixed duration. You don't have "frames"; you're just looping ("like crazy"). I would suggest a (dispatcher) timer; where you do your processing during the "timer interval"; without doing "sleeps" etc. The (stopwatched) work you do during the interval, compared to the total interval duration, will tell you what frame rate (FPS) to expect (at least 20 FPS (50ms per frame) in my experience). If you use UWP or WPF "storyboarding",  you can expect 60 FPS.
